# Pass nested JSON data into Html table format

Tags: python, html, json, python-3.x

I am trying to create an HTML report which contains the field and its value over tabular Html format using python.

data.json

```
[
    {
      "count": 0,
      "company": "abc",
      "state": {
        "city": {}
      },
      "name": "Techno",
      "age": 17,
      "file": "cubix.so"
    },
    {
        "count": 12,
        "company": "def",
        "state": {
          "city": {}
        },
        "name": "Uni",
        "age": 8,
        "file": "cyp.so"
      }
]
```

The requirement is to read JSON and fetch the file, name, and age values to pass in the Html report file.

```
def all_details():
    company=0
    age=0
    with open("data.json") as file:
        data = json.loads(file.read())
        for obj in data:
            print(obj['company'], obj['age'])
            message+="""<tr><th style="border:1px solid black;">File Name</th><th style="border:1px solid black;">Company</th><th style="border:1px solid black;">Age</th>"""
            for name in obj[file]:
                message += """<tr><td style="border:1px solid black;">""" + name + "</td>"
                message += """<td style="border:1px solid black;">""" + company + "</td>"
                message += """<td style="border:1px solid black;">""" + age + "</td>"
                message += "</tr>"
            message+="</table>"
            f = open('file.html','w')
            f.write(message)
            f.close()
```

need the expected Output in file.html:

[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @KlausD. requirement is to get the JSON values as attached in image in tabular format

Comment: Try converting json to pandas DF

Comment: Well, that is still no question. You have to ask a specific question about programming. So far you posted a task and some code and did not provide any hint what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1:**
You can convert JSON to pandas data frames and from DF to html

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_json('data.json')   # convert JSON to dataframe
df = df[["file","company","age"]] # select only required columns

html = df.to_html() # convert DF to html

print(html)
```

**Approach 2** : your method - just corrected few errors

```
def all_details():
    with open("data.json") as file:
        data = json.loads(file.read())
        message ="<table>"
        message +="""<tr><th style="border:1px solid black;">File Name</th><th style="border:1px solid black;">Company</th><th style="border:1px solid black;">Age</th>"""
        for obj in data:
            print(obj)
            print(obj['company'], obj['age'])
            
            if "name" in obj:
                message += """<tr><td style="border:1px solid black;">""" +  str(obj['name']) + "</td>"
                message += """<td style="border:1px solid black;">""" + str(obj['company']) + "</td>"
                message += """<td style="border:1px solid black;">""" + str( obj['age']) + "</td>"
                message += "</tr>"
        message+="</table>"
        f = open('file.html','w')
        f.write(message)
        f.close()
```

Comment: Without df approach

Comment: adding to same answer